# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable when import a function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Hi I am getting the following error.
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
I wrote a function module by myself,like this:

```
from numpy import *
import operator
def creatDataset() :
    group = array([[1.0,1.1],[1.0,1.0],[0,0],[0,0.1]])
    labels = ['A','A','B','B']
    return group,labels
```

then,I want to use this function in Microsoft's command window ,I've written some code, as follows:

```
import KNN
group,labels=KNN.creatDataset()
group()
```

when I input the code "**group()**",the error will appear.It's the first time that i describe the question and ask for help, maybe the description is not clear ，,please forgive me.

Comment: I have soved it,

Comment: Please answer your own question with how you solved this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Since "group" is a numpy.array, you cannot call it like a function.
So "group()" will not work.
I assume, you want to see it's values, so you would have to use something like
"print(group)".